# Remote access to network to windows 10 on dynamic IP

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-access

I'm trying to set up access to a machine in a remote network. Here I've tried to create a schema to show what I want to achieve:

[Connection to a remote network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dec8p.png)

My goal is to allow AdminPC to see TargetMachine the same way as it was in the same local network. TargetMachine can't have direct access to the Internet. It's a dumb device connected to ClientPC with LAN cable.

Some more info about the case:

- ClientPC has a dynamic IP address
- ClientPC can be connected through a random router or phone hotspot or whatever
- Both AdminPC and ClientPC are WINDOWS 10 machines

Here's what I was trying to do first:

- Installed ZeroTier One to AdminPC and ClientPC
- Created a network in ZeroTier Central
- Connected both machines to the network with "Allow managed IP" checked

Result: The machines can see each other. Sometimes they become unreachable to each other for some reason ‍♂️ so the connection is kind of unstable. Searched for another option.

Another app I've tried:

- Installed LogmeIn Hamachi to ClientPC and AdminPC
- Created a network between them
- Connected both machines to the network

Result: ClientPC and AdminPC can see each other and connection is pretty stable.

How I test: Both laptops are connected to separate Guest and Internal connections on my router and can't see each other directly. ClientPC is connected to the internal network and AdminPC is on a guest connection. I'm trying to make AdminPc see local resources in an internal network by making a connection to ClientPC using Hamachi.

This is how far I've come. I tried to bridge network interfaces between Hamachi virtual interface and WiFi on ClientPC but without any luck. I still can't see any other machines in the ClientPC network. Maybe some of you had the same issue and could give me some hints on the solution?

Comment: I put the remote network behind an IPsec VPN router and access the network (and computers on that network) by VPN access.  The external IP is dynamic but changes only about every 18 months. If need be, you can use DynDNS to achieve a static IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. ClientPC is a laptop so it can change physical place and also access points to the internet. One day it might connect to a wifi, another day it might connect to a hotspot on a mobile phone. That's why Im trying to use Hamachi or something similar.

Comment: You could try software VPN like Nord VPN or one of the services like it.

Comment: But I've managed to connect to the ClientPC using Hamachi. What I want to do next is to access a device connected directly to ClientPC over LAN cable.

Comment: I thought you were talking about truly remote access. Access via a LAN cable does not inform remote access.

Comment: have you checked the link to the schema in the description? I've tried to describe what I want to achieve there. It's AdminPC -> internet -> ClientPC -> LAN -> TargetMachine. My goal is for AdminPC to see TargetMachine as it was in the local network for it.

Comment: The "Internet" in the middle means traversing external IP addresses. That is not a LAN connection and that is why you need VPN to connect the LAN segments across diverse external IP addresses.

Comment: right, and Hamachi does exactly that. Sorry, I wasn't clear about that. And Hamachi provides with 10.x.x.x IP addresses assigned to AdminPC and ClientPC. And then the ClientPC has this TargetMachine connected over LAN that gets random IP addresses assigned (169.x.x.x for example). My question was how to merge those networks together to put ClientPC, AdminPC and TargetMachine in the same network range or something.

Comment: You would need a Hamachi expert for that.